# Is there a way to "dull" new solid exterior stain?

Tags: stain

I have had to touch up some places on the exterior of my house with solid exterior gloss after installing a new front door and putting on a back deck. But the stain appears so shiney next to the other boards.  Is there anyway to make it look duller?

Answer (score 1):

Use some extra fine grade steel wool and lightly go over it.